# Unable to query Dynamo at {tableName}

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

So I am getting the following error inside a lambda function when it attempts to read from a dynamo table where the query uses one of the GSI's on the table:

```
Unable to query Dynamo at XXXTable
```

Now I have both the lambda and the dynamo table defined in a cloudformation file.

Here is the policy that gives the lambda the permission to access the dynamo table.

```
LambdaPolicy:
Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
Properties:
  Roles:
    - !Ref LambdaRole
  PolicyName: LambdaPolicy
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "logs:*"
        Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "dynamodb:BatchGetItem"
          - "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
          - "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
          - "dynamodb:GetItem"
          - "dynamodb:PutItem"
          - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
          - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
          - "dynamodb:Query"
          - "dynamodb:Scan"
        Resource:
          - !GetAtt XXXTable.Arn
```

where XXXTable is a Dynamo table that is defined in the same cloudformation file.
Now I know I can manually solve this through the console by editing the lambda policy and adding this line to the Resource:

```
- "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:accountNubmer:table/XXXTable/index/*"
```

But the question, how do I add this to the cloudformation file?
Something like:

```
!GetAtt XXXTable.Arn + "/index/*
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing the `!Sub` function to combine them together. Try:

```
- !Sub "${XXXTable.Arn}/index/*"
```

Comment: Yep, I actually used the !Join intrinsic function to achieve the same thing.